# Best way to design a simple Library in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to the whole ASP and C# thing and have been experimenting by coding some very simple applications. An example of this is an extremly simple library application, it can function in 1 of the 2 follow ways:

The can be a Genre and a Book Model, each Genre contains many books, the Book has the GenreID as a foreign key. When a book is created it must be added to a specific Genre.

OR

There is only a Book Model and each Book model contains a string that is the Genre of that book. When a Book is created the Genre is set in the Model, to enumerate all Genres all Books in the database must be checked and any Genre that is found is listed.

Both of these options have their pros and cons but which one is really best for a very simple application, 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your application ASP.NET, or classic ASP?  You've tagged it both, but they're very different.

Comment: The traditional way would be your first way, with Genres and Books as separate entities. That would be much simpler to query and manage the database down the road. Many websites, like this one, use a concept of tags, which would provide more flexibility (eg, multiple "genres" per book), but would actually result in a more complicated data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide enough informations to really talk about the difficulty, but concerning design, to have a real "Genre" table/entity seems to me definitely to be the best solution. 
It will also provide a lighter database (no useless repetition of Genre between book records, only a foreign key)

As a beginner, how do you intend to access your database ? With an ORM like Entity Framework or Linq to sql, or requests directly written in SQL inside code behind ?
If you choose ORM, IMHO it will be simpler, faster, cleaner to use dedicated table for genre, even if it looks a bit harder at first glance.

Comment: You were right, creating a Genre model is the best way to go. The difficulties I was facing were mostly language related by after a lot of reading I got around them. Using foreign keys seems to be the clearest way to go and as people above said makes the database nice and compact.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want to do the separate Genre and use a foreign key. What if a Genre needs to be renamed? With the FK you just update the one Genre record. If the Genre is stored as a string on the Book you would need to update all books etc.